# Linux "CentOS 7" - General Fdisk Question

Tags: linux, centos, fdisk

I have a CentOS 7 Virtual Machine (VM).  I add a new disk to a VM with VMware workstation.  Then on the guest CentOS VM, I run the fdisk command, to start adding the partitions that I want. After I specify p to add a primary partition, I see output like follows:

*Partition number (1-4): 1
First cylinder (1-47536, default 1):
Using default value 1
Last cylinder or +size or +sizeM or +sizeK (1-47536, default 47536):
Using default value 47536*

My question relates to the 1st line of italic text above.  Why does it say (1-4)?  Are you not allowed to have more than 4 partitions on a single disk?

Comment: Pretty simple to answer with web search...

Comment: What would a root partition be considered, a primary partition?

How about a swap partition and convenience partitions like /boot, 
/home, /usr, /opt, /tmp, /usr/src, are these extended partitions?

Comment: Read the section "MBR Partitions" in this [PDF](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/l-lpic1-102-1/l-lpic1-102-1-pdf.pdf). These are partitions on disk "a": `sda1` `sda2`. These are partations on disk "b": `sdb1` `sdb3`. The directories or mount points you listed like root `/`; `/boot`; `/usr`; `/tmp` may be all on the same disk partition `/sda1` or multiple disk partitions `/sda6`. The disk partitions can be  primary, extended or logical, so the mount point `/tmp` does not determine the partition type.

Answer (score 1):

That's correct. You're only allowed 4 primary partitions. And you typically use one of those 4 to create an "extended" partition, which contains partitions 5 and up (the logical partitions). You can many logical partitions.

Answer (score 0):

You are only allowed to have 4 primary partitions. It has been that way since 1981. The reason is that the standard Master Boot record only has room for a partition table containing four entries.

Extended partitions are created by using a rather tortuous chaining of boot records in the actual partitions. That number is *theoretically* not limited, although if used on DOS/Windows you would soon run out of drive letters!

Another option is to use a GPT based solution - this replaces the Master Boot Record. But for now, once you've created a primary partition, `fdisk` will allow you to do other things. How many partitions do you want?

Comment: Thank you for feedback, have details on the comment I posted below original question?  I'm not sure if your familiar with this site, but I was running through direction for Linux From Scratch (LFS) at http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/lfs/view/stable/chapter02/creatingpartition.html